# Pound Sign Simplexml_load_string issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, simplexml

I have a php scrip that uses the following code to grad an xml file and then enter it into a mysql database.

It works really well apart from all of the pound signs display as Â£.

The xml is encoded as utf-8.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$params = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), 1);

//DETAILS TO INSERT
$contact_url = $params['contact_url']; 

etc
```

Does anybody know why this would be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pound sign is 0xC2 0xA3 in UTF-8; the bytes reported in the error message are the ISO-8859-1 characters:

[ pound sign ] [ 7 ] [ 0 ] [ 0 ]

so I think your document is in fact encoded as iso-8859-1 despite the declaration which indicates utf-8.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've double checked the xml and it definitely is utf-8